# Actionscript to Obj-C / Cocoa: How to represent BitmapData?

Tags: objective-c, actionscript-3, cocoa

I'm trying to port the [as3delaunay library](https://github.com/nodename/as3delaunay) to Obj-C (for fun and to learn some more Obj-C). It's going pretty well, but I don't really understand how to convert uses of `BitmapData` to Cocoa. Here are several of the relevant parts of the aforementioned library:

In `Edge.as`:

```
    internal function makeDelaunayLineBmp():BitmapData
    {
        var p0:Point = leftSite.coord;
        var p1:Point = rightSite.coord;

        GRAPHICS.clear();
        // clear() resets line style back to undefined!
        GRAPHICS.lineStyle(0, 0, 1.0, false, LineScaleMode.NONE, CapsStyle.NONE);
        GRAPHICS.moveTo(p0.x, p0.y);
        GRAPHICS.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);

        var w:int = int(Math.ceil(Math.max(p0.x, p1.x)));
        if (w < 1)
        {
            w = 1;
        }
        var h:int = int(Math.ceil(Math.max(p0.y, p1.y)));
        if (h < 1)
        {
            h = 1;
        }
        var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(w, h, true, 0);
        bmp.draw(LINESPRITE);
        return bmp;
    }
```

That is called in the following function, in `selectNonIntersectingEdges.as`:

```
internal function selectNonIntersectingEdges(keepOutMask:BitmapData, edgesToTest:Vector.<Edge>):Vector.<Edge>
{
    if (keepOutMask == null)
    {
        return edgesToTest;
    }

    var zeroPoint:Point = new Point();
    return edgesToTest.filter(myTest);

    function myTest(edge:Edge, index:int, vector:Vector.<Edge>):Boolean
    {
        var delaunayLineBmp:BitmapData = edge.makeDelaunayLineBmp();
        var notIntersecting:Boolean = !(keepOutMask.hitTest(zeroPoint, 1, delaunayLineBmp, zeroPoint, 1));
        delaunayLineBmp.dispose();
        return notIntersecting;
    }
}
```

It also appears as a parameter in `SiteList.as`:

```
    public function nearestSitePoint(proximityMap:BitmapData, x:Number, y:Number):Point
    {
        var index:uint = proximityMap.getPixel(x, y);
        if (index > _sites.length - 1)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return _sites[index].coord;
    }
```

What would be a good way to represent this behavior and/or the use of BitmapData in Obj-C / Cocoa?

Comment: In the `makeDelaunayLineBmp()` function, what is `LINESPRITE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Core Graphics library has very powerful graphics capabilities -- even though it's all C based. You can create an 8-bit RGBA (red, green, blue, alpha) bitmap context like this:

```
size_t const bytesPerRow = 4 * width;
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorspace, bitmapInfo);
CFRelease(colorspace);
```

This corresponds to what the AS3 BitmapData has.

`ctx` now has a reference to the bitmap context which you eventually have to release with `CGContextRelease(ctx)`.

You can *manipulate* the context, i.e. draw into it with the various `CGContext*` functions. If you eventually need to save it as an image (e.g. JPEG data), use `CGBitmapContextCreateImage()`.

Comment: Thanks! This will get me headed in the proper direction.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are needing a CGBitmapContext to use in place of the BitmapData type.

Things to look into:

- [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203) read the "Graphics Context" section, especially the "Creating a Bitmap Graphics Context" part.
- [CGBitmapContext reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html)